# How to write Utility class so that i can perform lazy loading with DTO design pattern?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, dto

As i know DTO is used to transfer the objects from one layer to other layers.
In my project i am using DTO to transfer the objects from persistance layer to service layer.

Here is my Utility class file which helps me to tranfrom persistance object to DTO.

PropertyUtil

```
    package com.cac.util;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import com.cac.hibernate.Answers;
import com.cac.hibernate.Members;
import com.cac.hibernate.Questions;
import com.cac.hibernate.Sections;
import com.cac.to.AnswersTO;
import com.cac.to.MembersTO;
import com.cac.to.QuestionsTO;
import com.cac.to.SectionsTO;
public class PropertyUtil {
    public static Sections getSectionsFromSectionsTO(SectionsTO sectionsto) {
        Sections sections=new Sections();
        sections.setSection_id(sectionsto.getSection_id());
        sections.setSection_name(sectionsto.getSection_name());
        sections.setSection_desc(sectionsto.getSection_desc());
        sections.setThreads(sectionsto.getThreads());
        sections.setPosts(sectionsto.getPosts());
        sections.setLast_post(sectionsto.getLast_post());
        sections.setLast_post_by(PropertyUtil.getMembersFromMembersTO(sectionsto.getLast_post_by()));
        sections.setQuestion_id(sectionsto.getQuestion_id());
        return sections;
    }
    public static SectionsTO getSectionsTOFromSections(Sections sections) {
        SectionsTO sectionsto=new SectionsTO();
        sectionsto.setSection_id(sections.getSection_id());
        sectionsto.setSection_name(sections.getSection_name());
        sectionsto.setSection_desc(sections.getSection_desc());
        sectionsto.setThreads(sections.getThreads());
        sectionsto.setPosts(sections.getPosts());
        sectionsto.setLast_post(sections.getLast_post());
        sectionsto.setLast_post_by(PropertyUtil.getMembersTOFromMembers(sections.getLast_post_by()));
        sectionsto.setQuestion_id(sections.getQuestion_id());
        Set<Questions> questions_set=sections.getQuestions_set();
        Set<QuestionsTO> questions_set_to=new HashSet<QuestionsTO>();
        Iterator<Questions> it=questions_set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            QuestionsTO questionsto=PropertyUtil.getQuestionsTOFromQuestions(it.next());
            questions_set_to.add(questionsto);
        }
        return sectionsto;
    }

    public static Members getMembersFromMembersTO(MembersTO membersto) {
        Members members=new Members();
        members.setMember_id(membersto.getMember_id());
        members.setUsername(membersto.getUsername());
        members.setPassword(membersto.getPassword());
        members.setEmail(membersto.getEmail());
        members.setGender(membersto.getGender());
        members.setBdate(membersto.getBdate());
        members.setImage_path(membersto.getImage_path());
        members.setAddress(membersto.getAddress());
        members.setBest_at(membersto.getBest_at());
        members.setPosition(membersto.getPosition());
        members.setJoin_date(membersto.getJoin_date());
        //Set<Members> memset=new HashSet<Members>();

        //members.setQuestions_set(membersto.getQuestionsto_set());
        //mem
        return members;
    }
    public static MembersTO getMembersTOFromMembers(Members members) {
        MembersTO membersto=new MembersTO();
        membersto.setMember_id(members.getMember_id());
        membersto.setUsername(members.getUsername());
        membersto.setPassword(members.getPassword());
        membersto.setEmail(members.getEmail());
        membersto.setGender(members.getGender());
        membersto.setBdate(members.getBdate());
        membersto.setImage_path(members.getImage_path());
        membersto.setAddress(members.getAddress());
        membersto.setBest_at(members.getBest_at());
        membersto.setPosition(members.getPosition());
        membersto.setJoin_date(members.getJoin_date());
        Set<Questions> questions_set=members.getQuestions_set();
        Set<QuestionsTO> questions_set_to=new HashSet<QuestionsTO>();
        Iterator<Questions> it=questions_set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            QuestionsTO questionsto=PropertyUtil.getQuestionsTOFromQuestions(it.next());
            questions_set_to.add(questionsto);
        }
        Set<Answers> answers_set=members.getAnswers_set();
        Set<AnswersTO> answers_set_to=new HashSet<AnswersTO>();
        Iterator<Answers> answers_it=answers_set.iterator();
        while(answers_it.hasNext()) {
            AnswersTO answersto=PropertyUtil.getAnswersTOFromAnswers(answers_it.next());
            answers_set_to.add(answersto);
        }
        //members.setQuestions_set(membersto.getQuestionsto_set());
        //mem
        return membersto;
    }
    public static QuestionsTO getQuestionsTOFromQuestions(Questions questions) {
        QuestionsTO questionsto=new QuestionsTO();
        questionsto.setQuestion_id(questions.getQuestion_id());
        questionsto.setQuestion_title(questions.getQuestion_title());
        questionsto.setQuestion_desc(questions.getQuestion_desc());
        questionsto.setQ_post_date(questions.getQ_post_date());
        questionsto.setReplies(questions.getReplies());
        questionsto.setViews(questions.getViews());
        questionsto.setLast_post_by(questions.getLast_post_by());
        questionsto.setLast_post_date(questions.getLast_post_date());

        Set<Answers> answers_set=questions.getAnswers_set();
        Set<AnswersTO> answers_set_to=new HashSet<AnswersTO>();
        Iterator<Answers> answers_it=answers_set.iterator();
        while(answers_it.hasNext()) {
            AnswersTO answersto=PropertyUtil.getAnswersTOFromAnswers(answers_it.next());
            answers_set_to.add(answersto);
        }
        return questionsto;
    }
    public static Questions getQuestionsFromQuestionsTO(QuestionsTO questionsto) {
        Questions questions=new Questions();
        questions.setQuestion_id(questionsto.getQuestion_id());
        questions.setQuestion_title(questionsto.getQuestion_title());
        questions.setQuestion_desc(questionsto.getQuestion_desc());
        questions.setQ_post_date(questionsto.getQ_post_date());
        questions.setReplies(questionsto.getReplies());
        questions.setViews(questionsto.getViews());
        questions.setLast_post_by(questionsto.getLast_post_by());
        questions.setLast_post_date(questionsto.getLast_post_date());

        return questions;
    }

    public static AnswersTO getAnswersTOFromAnswers(Answers answers) {
        AnswersTO answersto=new AnswersTO();
        answersto.setAnswer_id(answers.getAnswer_id());
        answersto.setAnswer_desc(answers.getAnswer_desc());
        answersto.setA_post_date(answers.getA_post_date());

        return answersto;
    }
    public static Answers getAnswersFromAnswersTO(AnswersTO answersto) {
        Answers answers=new Answers();
        answers.setAnswer_id(answersto.getAnswer_id());
        answers.setAnswer_desc(answersto.getAnswer_desc());
        answers.setA_post_date(answersto.getA_post_date());

        return answers;
    }
}
```

The thing is that whenever i have to perform lazy loading but when i use getSectionsTOFromSection() it will load all the persistence class.
.
So how to write this PropertyUtil class so that i can use lazy loading and DTO design pattern both ?

Answer (score 1):

Lazy fetching strategy lets you decide how much of the object graph should be loaded in the first database hit and which associations should be loaded lazily. And you are using DTO to transfer the objects from persistance layer to service layer.They are two completely different concepts. One is to load data from DB and the other is to transfer data among different layers.

Now for lazy loading, the recommended way is to configure all the associations for lazy fetching in the mapping file(with `lazy="true"`), which may then be overridden at runtime (wherever these is a need of an eager fetching).

Lets consider these two scenarios:

- There may be a need to fetch a list of the `Sections` (but you don't want the `associations` of the individual `Sections` objects to be loaded):

This list can be fetched using

```
session.createQuery("from Sections sections");
```

where the `Sections` present in the returned `list` will not contain the `associations`.

- You may again want to fetch a list of `Sections` with the associations fetched eagerly. This can be achieved by an outer join using the `fetch` keyword in the `from` clause (overriding the default fetching behavior):

> session.createQuery("from Sections sections left join fetch
>   sections.association-name");

When executed, this will return a list of Section instances, with its associations fully initialized.

Now, once you have the data loaded, you can use the DTOs to transfer the data to the service layer.

Comment: This is the point where i am facing problem. I have the list of sections object but when i am transforming List<Sections> to List<SectionsTO> property util come into action and you can see the propertyutil class it will load all the list of sections,questions,answers please have a look at getSectionsTOFromSections() in propertyutil class.

Comment: @user528050 Your code creates and populates the `Sections` object that is being passed to the `getSectionsTOFromSections` method. So your code can set its properties before passing it to `getSectionsTOFromSections`. Whenever you don't want the `associations` to be loaded, use this "from Sections sections" to fetch the `Sections` and before passing it to the `getSectionsTOFromSections` method, set the `association` values to empty sets. For example, set the questions set as `sections.setQuestionsSet(new HashSet<Question>(0))`.

Comment: With this, `sections.getQuestionsSet()` will not throw `LazyInitializationException`, because this will now return the empty set that had been to `Sections` before it was passed to `getSectionsTOFromSections`.

Comment: Many thanks for your interest But i have the requirement that when i try to do the lazy initialization of association i can able to do.

Comment: thats the default behavior you will get by setting `lazy="true"`. This will initialize your `associations` lazily. Now to override this, fetch them eagerly by using an outer join.

Comment: But i am not able to convert persistance class to DTO because if i do it will load all the class as i used getSectionsTOFromSections() but i have to load it lazily. when i click something on jsp page i want to perform lazy loading but calling sectionto.getQuestionsSet().